# Heavy TPL background threads produce lags in WPF's UI-Thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a WPF-application that uses several background threads for precompiling LINQ-queries and precaching some values, that will be needed later. TPL is used to start these tasks by:

```
var newTask = new Task(taskAction, myCancelToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
newTask.Start();
```

This works, the tasks are distributed over several cpu cores etc. However, these threads cause a high cpu load, that is perceptible in the UI, which tends to stumble or even freeze, as long as threads aren't finished.

So, what could be a reasonable way to smoothen UI. By researching I found, that one's not supposed to give threads special priorities. Others mean, frequent use of Thread.Sleep() was the way to go, which seems a bit outworn and hacky to me.

Are there additional ways I'm not aware of? Are there real disadvantages of priorizing threads (which isn't possible via TPL directly, afaik)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` creates new threads instead of using the thread pool. How many threads are you starting and how many cores do your target machines have?

Comment: I'm starting about ten or twelve tasks. The LongRunning-mode was just a try, I started without that and had the same result. The number of cores may differ, as there is no special dedicated target system setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 threads is too many on say a 4-core machine. If they are compute-bound like pre-compiling queries, they will all be contesting for cpu time and will make the whole machine unresponsive.

I suggest you use `Environment.ProcessorCount` to find out how many cores are available, and only start ( that number - 1 ) threads at a time. You can prioritise which work runs first and queue the others as continuations.

This will leave a core free to service your UI thread and should make the app responsive again.

Comment: But isn't TPL designed to distribute its tasks over a number of threads, that is calculated according to systems setup & performance, including number of cpus/cores? Therefor I meant I start ~12 tasks, not 12 worker threads. Meanwhile I removed TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, but as I said, this had no effect.

Comment: When you specify `LongRunning`, you are saying you want a new thread and you want it to run immediately. If you use normal tasks, they are subject to the thread pool thread injection / retirement algorithm which has it's own ideas, but always tries to use the whole machine. I'm suggesting leaving one core free all the time, which you will have to schedule manually.

Comment: So this leads to write a custom TaskScheduler that restricts the number of concurrent threads to ProcessorCount - 1.

Comment: There's one [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx) you could use.

Comment: This answer is in no way correct, a computer can run many 1000xCPU core threads. Of cause if you overload your CPU will your program start lagging, this will only happen when you reach a CPU usage of 100%. Other then that is the UI thread higher priority then then your background working threads.
A thread will not block a core until it is done, each thread is given an amount of time to work in before it will more to the next thread.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning prioritizing of tasks, you could do smth like
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2011/01/29/how-to-schedule-task-on-different-thread-priority.aspx

But AFAIK explicit changing of thread priority is not recommended practice

Comment: I read about changing thread priority being not recommended. But why, since it's actual possible? So does it, in turn mean, if there is much background work to do, I just have to live with a poor performing UI?